# Can I use the bend command in my coding?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, every node/.style={draw, shape=circle,fill,scale=0.5}]
\path (0,0) node (p1) {}
(-1.5,-1) node (p6) {}
(-1.5,-2.5) node (p5) {}
(1.5,-2.5) node (p3) {}
(1.5,-1) node (p2) {}
(0,-3.5) node (p4) {};
\draw (p1) -- (p2)
(p2) -- (p3)
(p3) -- (p4)
(p5) -- (p6)
(p6) -- (p1)
(p6) -- (p1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you see I got two of the same edge (p6) -- (p1).
I googled it and saw that in some codes different for this I can use a bend command is there some way that could work on this? If yes could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `to` path command, which allows you to draw curved paths.

The simplest way to use this is to replace `--` with `to [bend left]` or `to [bend right]`. This will curve the path at a 30° angle:

```
 \draw (0,0) to [bend left] (2,0);
```

[image]

You can also specify the curve angle, using `bend left=<angle>`:

```
\draw (0,0) to [bend left=90] (2,0);
```

[image]

Or you can specify the starting and ending angles, using `in=<angle>, out=<angle>`:

```
\draw (0,0) to [out=0, in=-90] (2,0);
```

[image]

More options are described in Section `51.3 Curves` of the [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual).

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={fill,circle,minimum size=2mm,inner sep=0pt}]
\path 
(0,0)       coordinate[dot] (p1) 
(-1.5,-1)   coordinate[dot] (p6) 
(-1.5,-2.5) coordinate[dot] (p5) 
(1.5,-2.5)  coordinate[dot] (p3) 
(1.5,-1)    coordinate[dot] (p2) 
(0,-3.5)    coordinate[dot] (p4) ;
\draw (p1) -- (p2)
      (p2) -- (p3)
      (p3) -- (p4)
      (p5) -- (p6)
      (p6) -- (p1)
      (p6) to[bend left] (p1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]