# How to draw pictures in latex

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How to draw this picture in latex?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Combine http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3172/586 with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53181/586 and/or http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358874/586 and you should be able to do most of that.

Comment: See `tikz-cd`or `pst-node` package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a kind of "do it for me"-question instead of "I have a specific problem with my try to make something"-question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a start, showing three different ways of connecting two nodes: straight lines (`--`), bent ones of limited curvature (`to[bend ...]`), and bent ones with greater flexibility but more complex (`.. controls +() and +() ..`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
   blob/.style={circle,fill,minimum width=2pt,inner sep=0pt},
   flow/.style={postaction={decorate}}
  ]
  \node[blob,label=above:N] (N) at (0, 0) {};
  \node[blob,label=below:S] (S) at (0,-3) {};
  \draw[flow] (S) .. controls +(-1.5,0) and +(-1.5,0) .. node[left]{$a_1$} (N);
  \draw[flow] (S) to[bend left=40]node[left]{$a_2$} (N);
  \draw[flow] (S) -- node[left] {$a_3$} (N);
  \draw[flow] (S) to[bend right=40]node[right]{$a_4$} (N);
  \draw[flow] (S) .. controls +(1.5,0) and +(1.5,0) .. node[right]{$a_5$} (N);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```